# key board selection for table sorter plugin for selecting rows

Tags: jquery

I am using table sorter plugin for sorting and displaying data in grid view.I was surfing to select a row using keyboard up,down arrow with multiple select but i could n't find it.

Can any one tell me how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `.focus()` and when a row gets focus, give it a class of selected, then use jquery to do something with the selected classes:

```
$(".selectedClass").each(function(){
  // your code
});
```

***Update (16:35 GMT):***

Right this took sometime and bare in mind that this is a starting point for you, not a finished product. Check it out here - http://jsfiddle.net/u7PMe/

It makes use of `.selectable()` and `keypress()`

If you're happy that this is a good starting point please accept the answer.

Comment: @Alex Thomas:I used this but this is n't working 
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 40) { //down arrow
 $('#tablesorter').click();
}
if(e.keyCode == 38 { //up arrow
 $('#tablesorter').click();
}
});

Comment: @Alex Thomas:Unexpected token

Comment: @Alex Thomas:I solved the bug in code but this code doesn't do what i want.

Comment: Can you add some code to the question, send an example, or upload some code to jsfiddle.

Comment: @stephen "Can you send me in jsfiddle to select using mouse" not sure what youre asking of me here. Also "Leave my code", if by this you mean you're not going to give example code, you're going to find it very difficult getting help on here.

Comment: The small javascript code that you posted in your second comment is close to useless, without some markup to go with it.

Comment: @Alex Thomas: That is only code i ued and it didn't work.You can give me a snippet which works by key board up and down arrow to high light multiple rows.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, sorry it took so long, turns out this is a non trivial request :S Check out my updated answer, hopefully this should give you a good start.